# How to pass array to xlsx-template package

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, json, xls

Im trying to pass a result from a query for the xlsx-template package in nodejs, but its not working. I swear I tryed everything, without any success.

Can anyone help me please?

json is my variable with recordset from database.

```
return JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result.recordset));


const { XLSXPopulateTemplate } = require('@tormozz48/xlsx-template');
await xlsxPopulateTemplate.loadTemplate(path.resolve('templates/modelo.xlsx'));

 xlsxPopulateTemplate.applyData({data: json});
```

Its returns me the following error:

```
TypeError: object null is not iterable (cannot read property Symbol(Symbol.iterator))
```